# HTML / CSS based Video opener not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I'm currently running out of guesses, but I've implemented a fullscreen video header on some sites of my webpage using WebM and a JPG replacement image as fallback shall the original MP4 video not be able to load

The header loads perfectly fine on 2 Macs as well as several smaller devices (tablets and smartphones across operating systems) however, some people that I've asked to test the website reported that the video does not load across browsers, and neither does the image fallback.

I've examined the code already a couple of times. Here's an example:

http://crispin-m.de/bentley.html

does it load in your browser? Where is the mistake that I've made?

Regards

Comment: Try to collect more details about those that doesn't work: internet connection speed, was there a VPN connected, operating system, browser, etc.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).